# Understanding Big-O notation in an equation

Tags: limits, asymptotics

My professor has in her notes the following equation:

$\left(1-\frac{1}{K}\right)^{K-i}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1-p}{K}\right)^{i}\right]=\frac{i(1-p)}{K}+O\left(\left(\frac{i}{K}\right)^{2}\right)$

Here, we are intereted in the asymptotic regime of $K$. The variable $i$ is an integer and can range from $1$ to $K$ .

I don't understand how the RHS is obtained. Can someone help me to understand how we go from LHS to RHS.

Comment: Binomial expansion might help ...

Comment: Which results do you obtain?

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE  Are you referring to $\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1-p}{K}\right)^{i}\right] \leq \frac{i(1-p)}{k}$

Comment: Yes. Can you obtain a similar expansion for your lead term?

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE $\left(1-\frac{1}{K}\right)^{K-i} \leq 1- \frac{k-i}{k}+\frac{(k-i)(k-i-1)}{2k^2}$. Is that right?

Comment: With respect to which variable are you considering O?

Comment: It's wrt $K$ and $i$ as the expressions indicate

Comment: The rhs needs to be divded by $e$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici RHS of the equation in the question? Could you explain why? I am not sure why.

Comment: If you write "wrt K and i ", then does it mean, that we are speaking about two variables? If yes, then how you define big-O wrt 2 variables? Or it is considered ratio $i/K$ as variable?

Comment: Yes $i/K$ as the variable